# navigation yields velocity on Y axis

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, all,

I am using navigation stack, move_base, for a simple navigation implementation.
my base is driven by two differential wheels, and rotates using speed difference between the two driving wheels. i.e. only speed on X axis and rotational speed

from time to time, speed on Y axis is received on "cmd_vel" topic, and the base doesn't know what to do with it.
how do I configure the move_base properly so that it generates velocity command that suits my robot base?

```
   ---
    linear: 
      x: 0.105263157895
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.157894736842
    ---
    linear: 
      x: 0.1
      ***y: -0.1***
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173628/navigation-yields-velocity-on-y-axis/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you have your local planner configured for a holonomic base, when your base isn't actually holonomic.

Without knowing exactly which local planner you're using, it's difficult to say exactly how to fix this. Fox example, `base_local_planner` has a parameter called `~/holonomic_robot` that you can set to false to disable this behavior, but I think the configuration is different for the `dwa_local_planner`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on 2014-06-15**:
yes. that was the reason. thanks.

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2018-06-10**:
Had the same issue. it seems that the `dwa_local_planner` does not handle non-holonomic vehicles. Changed it to `base_local_planner` and it works like a charm.